# Cannot insert Null value into Oracle database

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

How to add `NULL` value from `datepicker` to db?

```
strINSERT_INTO_DT = "Insert into BUYER_ENQUIRY_DT (DELIVERY_DATE,REF_DATE)Values"

strINSERT_INTO_DT += " '" & Convert.ToDateTime(dtFromGrid.Rows(i)("DELIVERY_DATE")).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") & "'"         

strINSERT_INTO_DT += ",'" & Convert.ToDateTime(dtFromGrid.Rows(i)("REF_DATE")).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") & "')"
```

Comment: I don't see an actual `INSERT` here.

Comment: how to add null values to oracle through convert.ToDateTime ().to string.Im Using date picker

Comment: @JesseJoseph, what he is telling you is to include your code for _inserting_.

Comment: The code is working fine, just want a way to accept null value from date picker.
So adding the complete code won't make any difference though,Still I have added rest of the code.

Comment: What type of cells "DELIVERY_DATE" and "REF_DATE" in your grid? Is it DateTime type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use prepared statements with bind variables. It works much better and NULL values are handled properly. Would be like this:

```
strINSERT_INTO_DT = "Insert into BUYER_ENQUIRY_DT (DELIVERY_DATE,REF_DATE) Values (:deliveryDate,refDate)"

cmd.Parameters.Add("deliveryDate", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = _
   CType(Convert.ToDateTime(dtFromGrid.Rows(i)("DELIVERY_DATE")), Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate)
cmd.Parameters.Add("refDate", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = _
   CType(Convert.ToDateTime(dtFromGrid.Rows(i)("REF_DATE")), Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your column in table allow null value.

Comment: He can't post comments yet.

Comment: It allow null values. im using date picker to enter the values.